# Thread.Sleep and Painting UI

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this stoplight program that models a strange intersection near where I live. I am pretty sure I have the logic down. I have functions that represent every possible state of the lights, including yellows. The problem is that none of my yellow lights are painting. Five seconds after a car pulls up to a light and no other cars have passed through green lights, yellow lights for appropriate lights are supposed to turn on for three seconds, and then turn green. For some reason when I step through my program, no yellow lights are painting. Here is my code:

```
private void WaitThreeSecs()
    {
        //somehow I think this is to blame
        int threeSeconds = 3000;
        Thread.Sleep(threeSeconds);
    }

    private void FromStateOneToTwo()
    {
        //Stop Countdown Timers
        fiveSec.Stop();
        thirtySec.Stop();

        //Indicate Current State
        CurrentState = 2;

        //Paint lights
        BottomGreen.Fill = gray;
        BottomYellow.Fill = yellow; // this never happens
        BottomRed.Fill = gray;

        //Wait 3 secs
        WaitThreeSecs();

        btnbottom.Content = "Car Stops";

        //Call function that changes the state for other lights to be green
        StateTwo();
    }
```

FromStateOneToTwo() is called after the five seconds, but the light is never yellow. I have no idea why this doesn't happen. The light waits 8 seconds from when a button is pressed to when the appropriate light goes straight from red to green, meaning that my 3 second timer is working, but my painting the light is not. (I paint in other function exactly like i do here, and it works fine)

I can show more/all of my code if needed.

Comment: I assume that code is invoked from the UI thread? Like directly off of a button click?

Comment: Actually, it sounds like the Timer is calling the function onto the UI thread, so you assumption is correct. The sleep is preventing the UI thread from updating the screen.

Comment: The function is a dispatchtimer eventhandler. 

So how would I go about allowing the Thread to update the screen and then wait 3 seconds?

Comment: Well, the function must be called onto the UI thread or else a Cross-Threading Exception would be raised the moment the function attempts to work with the button objects (ButtonTop.Fill = green).

Comment: @Wizetux Yes, I just realized that :)

Comment: I am new to multithreading. Is the main thread the UI thread? It seems to me (from my very limited understanding obviously) that the lights should paint, and THEN the sleep should happen.

Comment: Yes, the main thread is the UI thread, and events like `Paint` only occur after you return control (which `Thread.Sleep` prevents)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting a cross-thread `InvalidOperation` exception, so I'll assume that the provided function runs on the UI thread. This will happen if you invoke it off of a button-click, or the elapsed event of a `DispatcherTimer`.

By sleeping the UI thread, you don't give it time to paint the screen. It switches colors, then back, without a paint method ever running.

Your best solution is to use a standard `Timer` so you aren't on the UI thread, then marshal your changes to the UI thread with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (WPF) or `Control.Invoke`(WinForms). You can also eliminate `Thread.Sleep` and make more timers to trigger the next changes.

Answer (score -2):

Use `Application.DoEvents` right before the `WaitThreeSecs()` tot force a screen refresh

Comment: While this fixes the problem; it is almost *never* the right approach. Using it is a huge code smell, and there is a better way.

Comment: True, but thats not the issue here.

Comment: Do I have to add A "Using" to be able to do this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge (vb.net has it standard in windows.forms)

Comment: Just kidding, I think DoEvents is no longer supported because it is frowned upon.